# Нужно ли ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> День продержался до вечера серый, с нависшими тучами и ветром, вечером
>   после заката шел дождь(,) и ночью всё слышались капли…

Answer (score 2):

*День продержался до вечера серый, с нависшими тучами и ветром, **вечером** после заката шел дождь, и **ночью** всё слышались капли…*

Сложное предложение с бессоюзной и сочинительной связью, общего элемента (наречия) нет: в предложении 2  ― наречие *вечером*, в предложении 3 ― наречие *ночью*.